# how to print multiple ajax response values in php table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i have a problem with an ajax response, printing a table. My ajax code like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var terminalid=$('#terminal_id').val();
var pin=$('#pin').val();
var agentid=$('#agentid').val();

var agenterminal=terminalid.split(",");
var agent_id=agentid.split(",");
var agentaccountpin=pin.split(",");

var agr=[];
var pin_arr=[];
var ter_arr=[];

for (var i=0; i<agent_id.length; i++)
    agr.push( + agent_id[i] );

for (var j=0; j<agentaccountpin.length; j++)
    pin_arr.push( + agentaccountpin[j] );

for (var k=0; k<agenterminal.length; k++)
    ter_arr.push( + agenterminal[k] );

var final_arr=[];
for(var i=0; i<agr.length; i++)
{
    //alert(agr[i]);
    var datastring="terminal_id="+ter_arr[i]+"pin="+pin_arr[i]+"agentid="+agr[i];
    var geturl="myurl";
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:geturl,
        data:datastring,
        success: function(resp){
            alert(resp);
            $("#balance").html(resp);
        }

     });
}

});
```

This is my PHP code:

```
 foreach ($this->agent_summary_results as $row)
 {
        // Some Code for Data printing in table format
        <tr>
            <td class="Row" width="12%" valign="top" >name</td>
            <td valign=top width="12%" class="Row">credit bal</td>
            <td>
              <div id="balance"><FONT COLOR=RED size=3>Calculating...</FONT></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
$terminalid[]=$terminal_id;
      $account_card_pin[]=$pin;
      $id_agent[]=$agentid;
    }
$agentterminalid=implode(",", $terminalid);
  $agentaccountpin=implode(",",$account_card_pin);
  $agent_id=implode(",",$id_agent);
<input type="hidden" name="terminal_id" id="terminal_id" value="<?php echo $agentterminalid;?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="pin" id="pin" value="<?php echo $agentaccountpin;?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="agentid" id="agentid" value="<?php echo $agent_id;?>">
```

For example my o/p is like below
S.no   name   balance

1     tgest   12.34 
2     test    calculating..
3     sandy   calculating..

Like this i get the output. In ajax i get all responses. But in the table it is not displayed. Please help me. How to solve this. Thanks

The response prints in only first row. But i have total.

Comment: prepare table code and and use .html to replace. must be your table code is wrong

Comment: sorry i didnt understand what you said. i got response in multiples.it prints in only first row.

Comment: by doing this you're getting multiple div with same it balance so it will give you a error.

Comment: i didnt get any error. when i alert the response i get all results.while printing in html it prints only first row. how to print in all other rows

Comment: can you show what is the output?

Comment: ouput is added in my question.

Comment: Show your html response not only text and your id="balance" div too

Comment: i updated the php code. please check

Comment: You should print what you get from `alert(resp);`. Also you need to show your `#balance` container (as HTML).

Comment: You should not do ajax requests inside a loop. What if `#agentid` contains many ids ? You will have a lot of requests... You should construct a single javascript object and just put it as the request data

Comment: Thats right answer @Brewal.. could you give example for ajax how to send that one without loop.it will help me a lot

Comment: I am not sure about your php script. You should edit your question to put it whole. I made an answer anyway

Comment: ok.Thanks. i will edit my php script@Brewal

Answer (score 0):

You should construct a single javascript array within your loop and then send a single ajax request with this array as `data` :

```
var dataArray = [];

for(var i=0; i<agr.length; i++)
{
    dataArray.push({
        terminal_id: ter_arr[i],
        pin: pin_arr[i],
        agentid: agr[i]
    });
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myurl",
    data: {
        mydata: dataArray // You will have a "$_POST['mydata']" variable in PHP
    }, 
    success: function(resp){
        $("#balance").html(resp);
    }
});
```

Comment: In response again i need to add loop condition? or not needed

Comment: Your javascript should be like this. You already have a loop in your PHP that should result in multiple `<tr>`. Maybe it should be inserted in the `tbody` of the table : `$("#balance tbody").html(resp);`

Comment: i updated my code.please check once.i am getting error. what should i assign `$_POST['mydata']`..?

Comment: If your PHP script really is so... You forgot to put the HTML out of the php code : `?><tr>...</tr><?php`. What is the server response ? What is the output of the alert ? Can we see it in action ?